# Trying to run an application from Java

Tags: java, runtime, processbuilder

I need to run the "VBoxManage vms list command" to see the virtual machines installed on a computer from a Java application.

The following code works correctly but only if I use the Runtime class but I would like to know why it fails if I use ProcessBuilder.

The code is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String folder= "c:/Program files/Oracle/VirtualBox";
    List<String> comand = Arrays.asList(
        "VBoxManage",
        "list",
        "vms" 
    );
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
            .directory(new File(folder))
            .command(comand);

    Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

This works fine if I use the Runtime class with this code:
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = runtime.exec("c:/Program files/Oracle/VirtualBox/vboxmanage list vms");

Thank you.

Comment: Fails how exactly?

Comment: You use a different case for the name of the program with the ProcessBuilder. `VBoxManage` vs. `vboxmanage`

Comment: I tryed both but doesn't work

Comment: java indicates that can't find the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path of the executable, like you do when using Runtime.exec

```
List<String> comand = Arrays.asList(
    "c:/Program files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage",
    "list",
    "vms" 
);
```

Comment: This way it works correctly but I don't understand the reason. In the code I provide, I indicate the directory where you have to run the application. In fact, if instead of trying to run vBoxManager I run a "dir", it works correctly on the indicated directory.

Comment: When you try to run `VBoxManage` the operating system looks for an executable file called `VBoxManage.exe` in a few folders. "c:/Program files/Oracle/VirtualBox" is not one of them and that's why you get the error. The list of folders is controlled by "PATH environment variable" - search for that phrase to learn more.  "Directory" would set the program's current working directory, it does not help the operating system find the executable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand the problem. Using the "directory" method, I indicate the working directory where the application I want to run is, and even then, it does not run it. Instead, it does run a "dir", for example